# Rerun certain successful airflow task based on conditions

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a Dag for example with task A, B and C. Currently C dependents on both A and B. The thing is, I am trying to figure out a way to 1) run C after either A or B is successful, so that some columns in C will be refreshed. 2) Say A was completed first, and C was executed successfully once. Now B is completed. How can I now trigger C to run once again? This is a desired behavior to have c run twice. C might have more that 2 dependencies than A and B. What would be a way be incrementally update C and have it re-runable once more conditions are met?
The jobs A, B and C are Spark jobs or Hive sql. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. run C after either A or B is successful, so that some columns in C will be refreshed. 2) Say A was completed first, and C was executed successfully once. Now B is completed. How can I now trigger A to run once again?

The answer is in [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules). I would consider using `all_done` rule in C task. In this way it will run always after A and B (no matter what result). However, this may require to adjust task C to work properly in case if all task failed.

> How can I now trigger A to run once again? C might have more that 2 dependencies than A and B. What would be a way be incrementally update C and have it re-runable once more conditions are met?

To do that, from Airflow Web UI:

1. Mark task C as failed
2. Clear task C with options "upstream" and "failed":

[image]

This should rerun all failed task (either A or B or any other that is in upstream of C) as well as C (because we marked it as failed).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry maybe I did not explain it well. The thing is I sort of want `one_success` so that C will run after A or B finishes, and when the other one finishes, I do want C to run again. How to achieve this?

Comment: so have C running twice is the desired behavior

Comment: Then create a "C" task after every A and B task so you will have C_A, C_B task and so on. You can do this in loop, that's Airflow style.